# subtracting one json file from another in jq

Tags: arrays, json, object, jq, subtraction

Is there a way to compare two json files in jq? Specifically, I'd like to be able to remove objects from one json file if they occur in another json file. Basically, subtract one file from another. It would be a bonus if I could generalize this so that I could define the equality criteria for the objects, but this is not strictly necessary, it can be based strictly on the objects being identical.

So the more general case would look like this. Let's say I have a file that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Cynthia",
    "surname": "Craig",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,426.88"
  },
  {
    "name": "Elise",
    "surname": "Long",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$1,892.72"
  },
  {
    "name": "Hyde",
    "surname": "Adkins",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,769.34"
  },
  {
    "name": "Matthews",
    "surname": "Jefferson",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,991.42"
  },
  {
    "name": "Kris",
    "surname": "Norris",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$2,137.11"
  }
]
```

And I have a second file that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Cynthia",
    "surname": "Craig"
  },
  {
    "name": "Kris",
    "surname": "Norris"
  }
]
```

I'd like to remove any objects from the first file where the name and surname fields match an object of the second file, so that the results should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Elise",
    "surname": "Long",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$1,892.72"
  },
  {
    "name": "Hyde",
    "surname": "Adkins",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,769.34"
  },
  {
    "name": "Matthews",
    "surname": "Jefferson",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,991.42"
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes, but the details depend on the particulars, so please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In the example for your second file, you need to remove the trailing `,` after the `surname` key (`"surname": "Norris",`) because in JSON, unlike other languages, trailing commas after the last key of an object are not legal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following solution is intended to be generic, efficient and as simple as possible subject to the first two objectives.

### Genericity

For genericity, let us suppose that $one and $two are two arrays of
JSON entities, and that we wish to find those items, $x, in $one
such that ($x|filter) does not appear in map($two | filter), where `filter` is an arbitrary filter.  (In the present instance, it is `{surname, name}`.)

The solution uses `INDEX/1`, which was added to jq after the official 1.5 release, so we begin by reproducing its definition:

```
def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
  reduce stream as $row ({};
    .[$row|idx_expr|
      if type != "string" then tojson
      else .
      end] |= $row);
def INDEX(idx_expr): INDEX(.[]; idx_expr);
```

### Efficiency

For efficiency, we will need to use a JSON object as a dictionary;
since keys must be strings, we will need to ensure that when converting an object
to a string, the objects are normalized.  For this, we define `normalize` as follows:

```
# Normalize the input with respect to the order of keys in objects
def normalize:
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then reduce keys[] as $key
         ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | normalize) } ) 
    elif type == "array" then map( normalize )
    else .
    end;
```

To construct the dictionary, we simply apply (normalize|tojson):

```
def todict(filter):
  INDEX(filter| normalize | tojson);
```

#### The solution

The solution is now quite simple:

```
# select those items from the input stream for which 
# (normalize|tojson) is NOT in dict:
def MINUS(filter; $dict):
 select( $dict[filter | normalize | tojson] | not);

def difference($one; $two; filter):
  ($two | todict(filter)) as $dict
  | $one[] | MINUS( filter; $dict );

difference( $one; $two; {surname, name} )
```

#### Invocation

```
$ jq -n --argfile one one.json --argfile two two.json -f difference.jq
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which uses `--argfile` and `project/1` from [pull/1062](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/pull/1062/commits/02b4637d4f1742deb28aebecdbf89aed351e9480)

```
def project(q):
    . as $in
  | reduce (q | if type == "object" then keys[] else .[] end) as $k (
      {}
      ; . + { ($k) : ($in[$k]) }
    )
;

  map(
    reduce $arg[] as $a (
        .
      ; select(project($a) != $a)
    )
    | values
  )
```

If you place the "second" file in `second.json`, the data in `data.json` and the above filter in `filter.jq` you can run this with

```
jq -M --argfile arg second.json -f filter.jq data.json
```

to produce

```
[
  {
    "name": "Elise",
    "surname": "Long",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$1,892.72"
  },
  {
    "name": "Hyde",
    "surname": "Adkins",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,769.34"
  },
  {
    "name": "Matthews",
    "surname": "Jefferson",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,991.42"
  }
]
```

You can replace the expression `select(project($a) != $a)` with something else if you want to revise the equality criteria for the objects.

Thinking about this a little more we can eliminate the need for `project/1` by using `contains`.  This should be more efficient as it eliminates construction of a temporary object.

```
  map(
    reduce $arg[] as $a (
        .
      ; select(.!=null and contains($a)==false)
    )
    | values
  )
```

this can be further simplified using `any`:

```
map(select(any(.; contains($arg[]))==false))
```

which is short enough to be used directly on the command line:

```
jq -M --argfile arg second.json 'map(select(any(.; contains($arg[]))==false))' data.json
```

Answer (score 1):

***jq*** solution:

```
jq --slurpfile s f2.json '[ .[] | . as $o | if (reduce $s[0][] as $i
     ([]; . + [($o | contains($i))]) | any) then empty else $o end ]' f1.json
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Elise",
    "surname": "Long",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$1,892.72"
  },
  {
    "name": "Hyde",
    "surname": "Adkins",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,769.34"
  },
  {
    "name": "Matthews",
    "surname": "Jefferson",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,991.42"
  }
]
```